# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "deployer-conf" : object "pgo"/"pgo-deployer-cm" not registered

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, postgres-operator

Trying to install Crunchydata postgres-operator.
My pgo-deploy pod is failing with error.
I have setup default nfs storage running the following commands,
`# kubectl create -f rbac.yaml`
the content is,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner
  # replace with namespace where provisioner is deployed
  namespace: pgo
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-runner
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["persistentvolumeclaims"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "update"]
  - apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["storageclasses"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["events"]
    verbs: ["create", "update", "patch"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: run-nfs-client-provisioner
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nfs-client-provisioner
    # replace with namespace where provisioner is deployed
    namespace: pgo
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nfs-client-provisioner-runner
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: leader-locking-nfs-client-provisioner
  # replace with namespace where provisioner is deployed
  namespace: pgo
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["endpoints"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: leader-locking-nfs-client-provisioner
  # replace with namespace where provisioner is deployed
  namespace: pgo
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nfs-client-provisioner
    # replace with namespace where provisioner is deployed
    namespace: pgo
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: leader-locking-nfs-client-provisioner
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

`# kubectl create -f class.yaml`
the content:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: managed-nfs-storage
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: k8s-sigs.io/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner # or choose another name, must match deployment's env PROVISIONER_NAME'
parameters:
  archiveOnDelete: "false"
```

`# kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`
the content:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-client-provisioner
  labels:
    app: nfs-client-provisioner
  # replace with namespace where provisioner is deployed
  namespace: pgo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs-client-provisioner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nfs-client-provisioner
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nfs-client-provisioner
      containers:
        - name: nfs-client-provisioner
          image: k8s.gcr.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs-client-root
              mountPath: /persistentvolumes
          env:
            - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
              value: k8s-sigs.io/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
            - name: NFS_SERVER
              value: 192.168.10.114
            - name: NFS_PATH
              value: /var/nfs/general
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-client-root
          nfs:
            server: 192.168.10.114
            path: /var/nfs/general
```

Now when I apply `# kubectl apply -f postgres-operator.yml` with my configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: pgo-deployer-sa
  namespace: pgo
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pgo-deployer-cr
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - create
      - patch
      - delete
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs:
      - list
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - get
      - create
      - delete
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - services
      - persistentvolumeclaims
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - delete
      - list
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - serviceaccounts
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - delete
      - patch
      - list
  - apiGroups:
      - apps
      - extensions
    resources:
      - deployments
      - replicasets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
      - create
      - delete
  - apiGroups:
      - apiextensions.k8s.io
    resources:
      - customresourcedefinitions
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - delete
  - apiGroups:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - clusterroles
      - clusterrolebindings
      - roles
      - rolebindings
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - delete
      - bind
      - escalate
  - apiGroups:
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - roles
    verbs:
      - create
      - delete
  - apiGroups:
      - batch
    resources:
      - jobs
    verbs:
      - delete
      - list
  - apiGroups:
      - crunchydata.com
    resources:
      - pgclusters
      - pgreplicas
      - pgpolicies
      - pgtasks
    verbs:
      - delete
      - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pgo-deployer-cm
  namespace: pgo
data:
  values.yaml: |-
    # =====================
    # Configuration Options
    # More info for these options can be found in the docs
    # https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/latest/installation/configuration/
    # =====================
    archive_mode: "true"
    archive_timeout: "60"
    backrest_aws_s3_bucket: ""
    backrest_aws_s3_endpoint: ""
    backrest_aws_s3_key: ""
    backrest_aws_s3_region: ""
    backrest_aws_s3_secret: ""
    backrest_aws_s3_uri_style: ""
    backrest_aws_s3_verify_tls: "true"
    backrest_gcs_bucket: ""
    backrest_gcs_endpoint: ""
    backrest_gcs_key_type: ""
    backrest_port: "2022"
    badger: "false"
    ccp_image_prefix: "registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata"
    ccp_image_pull_secret: ""
    ccp_image_pull_secret_manifest: ""
    ccp_image_tag: "centos8-13.3-4.7.0"
    create_rbac: "true"
    crunchy_debug: "false"
    db_name: ""
    db_password_age_days: "0"
    db_password_length: "24"
    db_port: "5432"
    db_replicas: "0"
    db_user: "testuser"
    default_instance_memory: "128Mi"
    default_pgbackrest_memory: "48Mi"
    default_pgbouncer_memory: "24Mi"
    default_exporter_memory: "24Mi"
    delete_operator_namespace: "false"
    delete_watched_namespaces: "false"
    disable_auto_failover: "false"
    disable_fsgroup: "false"
    reconcile_rbac: "true"
    exporterport: "9187"
    metrics: "false"
    namespace: "pgo"
    namespace_mode: "dynamic"
    pgbadgerport: "10000"
    pgo_add_os_ca_store: "false"
    pgo_admin_password: "examplepassword"
    pgo_admin_perms: "*"
    pgo_admin_role_name: "pgoadmin"
    pgo_admin_username: "admin"
    pgo_apiserver_port: "8443"
    pgo_apiserver_url: "https://postgres-operator"
    pgo_client_cert_secret: "pgo.tls"
    pgo_client_container_install: "false"
    pgo_client_install: "true"
    pgo_client_version: "4.7.0"
    pgo_cluster_admin: "false"
    pgo_disable_eventing: "false"
    pgo_disable_tls: "false"
    pgo_image_prefix: "registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata"
    pgo_image_pull_secret: ""
    pgo_image_pull_secret_manifest: ""
    pgo_image_tag: "centos8-4.7.0"
    pgo_installation_name: "devtest"
    pgo_noauth_routes: ""
    pgo_operator_namespace: "pgo"
    pgo_tls_ca_store: ""
    pgo_tls_no_verify: "false"
    pod_anti_affinity: "preferred"
    pod_anti_affinity_pgbackrest: ""
    pod_anti_affinity_pgbouncer: ""
    scheduler_timeout: "3600"
    service_type: "ClusterIP"
    sync_replication: "false"
    backrest_storage: "nfsstorage"
    backup_storage: "nfsstorage"
    primary_storage: "nfsstorage"
    replica_storage: "nfsstorage"
    pgadmin_storage: "nfsstorage"
    wal_storage: ""
    storage1_name: "default"
    storage1_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
    storage1_size: "1G"
    storage1_type: "dynamic"
    storage2_name: "hostpathstorage"
    storage2_access_mode: "ReadWriteMany"
    storage2_size: "1G"
    storage2_type: "create"
    storage3_name: "nfsstorage"
    storage3_access_mode: "ReadWriteMany"
    storage3_size: "10Gi"
    storage3_type: "create"
    storage3_supplemental_groups: "65534"
    storage4_name: "nfsstoragered"
    storage4_access_mode: "ReadWriteMany"
    storage4_size: "1G"
    storage4_match_labels: "crunchyzone=red"
    storage4_type: "create"
    storage4_supplemental_groups: "65534"
    storage5_name: "storageos"
    storage5_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
    storage5_size: "5Gi"
    storage5_type: "dynamic"
    storage5_class: "fast"
    storage6_name: "primarysite"
    storage6_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
    storage6_size: "4G"
    storage6_type: "dynamic"
    storage6_class: "primarysite"
    storage7_name: "alternatesite"
    storage7_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
    storage7_size: "4G"
    storage7_type: "dynamic"
    storage7_class: "alternatesite"
    storage8_name: "gce"
    storage8_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
    storage8_size: "300M"
    storage8_type: "dynamic"
    storage8_class: "standard"
    storage9_name: "rook"
    storage9_access_mode: "ReadWriteOnce"
    storage9_size: "1Gi"
    storage9_type: "dynamic"
    storage9_class: "rook-ceph-block"
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pgo-deployer-crb
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pgo-deployer-cr
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: pgo-deployer-sa
    namespace: pgo
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pgo-deploy
  namespace: pgo
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      name: pgo-deploy
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: pgo-deployer-sa
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: pgo-deploy
          image: registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/pgo-deployer:centos8-4.7.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: DEPLOY_ACTION
              value: install
          volumeMounts:
            - name: deployer-conf
              mountPath: "/conf"
      volumes:
        - name: deployer-conf
          configMap:
            name: pgo-deployer-cm
```

I get the following error:

```
# kubectl get pods -n pgo
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nfs-client-provisioner-7d485f5b8d-cnt57   1/1     Running   0          28m
pgo-deploy--1-ppzkw                       0/1     Error     0          10m
```

`# kubectl describe pod -n pgo pgo-deploy--1-ppzkw` returns the following error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    9m13s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned pgo/pgo-deploy--1-ppzkw to dfsworker1
  Normal   Pulled       9m11s               kubelet            Container image "registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/pgo-deployer:centos8-4.7.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created      9m10s               kubelet            Created container pgo-deploy
  Normal   Started      9m10s               kubelet            Started container pgo-deploy
  Warning  FailedMount  8m58s (x3 over 9m)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "deployer-conf" : object "pgo"/"pgo-deployer-cm" not registered
```

even tried with `# kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/v4.7.1/installers/kubectl/postgres-operator.yml`
it gives the same error. `# kubectl -n pgo logs -f pgo-deploy--1-ppzkw` gives the following error:

```
TASK [pgo-operator : Create PGClusters CRD] ************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["kubectl", "create", "-f", "/ansible/postgres-operator/roles/pgo-operator/files/crds/pgclusters-crd.yaml"], "delta": "0:00:02.599141", "end": "2021-08-09 08:24:50.295545", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-08-09 08:24:47.696404", "stderr": "error: unable to recognize \"/ansible/postgres-operator/roles/pgo-operator/files/crds/pgclusters-crd.yaml\": no matches for kind \"CustomResourceDefinition\" in version \"apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1\"", "stderr_lines": ["error: unable to recognize \"/ansible/postgres-operator/roles/pgo-operator/files/crds/pgclusters-crd.yaml\": no matches for kind \"CustomResourceDefinition\" in version \"apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1\""], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=21   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=17   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? All my machines are ubuntu 20.04. It was all working with the same configurations and steps a few days ago until I deleted the `pgo` namespace and followed all my past procedures.
My kubernetes version: `v1.22.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you provided says what is wrong:

```text
error: unable to recognize \"/ansible/postgres-operator/roles/pgo-operator/files/crds/pgclusters-crd.yaml\": no matches for kind \"CustomResourceDefinition\" in version \"apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1\"
```

`CustomResourceDefinition` is no longer in beta API:

```text
kubectl explain CustomResourceDefinition
KIND:     CustomResourceDefinition
VERSION:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
```

Ideally, the editor in charge of that operator already ships with some up-to-date `CustomResourceDefinitions`. In your case, the last copy seems to be available [over here](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/blob/master/config/crd/bases/postgres-operator.crunchydata.com_postgresclusters.yaml).

Though if your CRD is outdated: there may be other changes you would want to pull out of Crunchy latest release.

Otherwise, we may consider rewriting those objects ourselves:

- change `apiVersion` to `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1`
- fix `spec` complying with the last schema

`spec.additionalPrinterColumns`, `spec.subresources` or `spec.validation` would need to move into a `spec.versions` array. You no longer have to define a schema for your resources metadata - if you did configure a schema in your CRD.

The new layout would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1     
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: crname.api-group
spec:
  group: api-group
  names:
    kind: CrName
    listKind: CrNameList
    plural: crnames
    singular: crname
  scope: Namespaced        
  versions:
  - name: v1
    additionalPrinterColumns: 
    - name: Age    
      type: date
      jsonPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    schema:   
      openAPIV3Schema:
        properties:
          apiVersion:
            type: string
          kind:
            type: string
          spec:   
            properties:                                                              
               [...]
        type: object                
    served: true            
    storage: true                                                                    
    subresources:                                                                  
      status: {}
  - name: v1beta1
    [...]
```

Comment: WARNING: the schema of CRD did change, between v1beta1 and v1. If we just replace the apiVersion, the apiserver would still refuse that object. Hopefully, we may find an up-to-date copy of that CRD, otherwise we need to comply with the new schema.

Comment: probably that one: https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator/blob/master/config/crd/bases/postgres-operator.crunchydata.com_postgresclusters.yaml

Comment: You are right, I changed my answer to CW, please add your comments to it.